# PySimpleGUI - Window being initialized event

Tags: pysimplegui

I just cannot find anywhere how to hook my setup code when the PySimpleGUI  is actually displayed and initialized

I tried printing events, nothing comes out until I use the ui itself

```
# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    print("EVENT: "+event)
```

Any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: `window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)`, after this statement, window finalized, then your setup code.

Comment: ok, but would'nt it be better to have an event ? all gui api do that

Comment: It is not an event if you know when to start your setup code and not triggered by an event. all GUI api do that ? IMO, all GUI api don't do that.